# Using Page Objects vs Config Files in Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, pageobjects

I've been using Ruby Selenium-Webdriver for one of the automation scripts I'm developing and I'm being asked to use Page Objects, we use page objects a lot however for this application I am using CSV file instead, I have defined all the xpaths that I'm using in my application in a CSV file and I'm parsing that CSV file in my script to refer to those objects, I would like to know is there much of a difference in using a class for defining Page Objects or using a CSV file instead apart from performance concern? I believe using a CSV file will be an addon for us from configuration standpoint and will make it much easier to maintain, any suggestions on this?

Edit - In our use case, we're actually automating applications built on a cloud based tool, so basically all the applications share same design structure from HTML standpoint so we define xpath patterns in CSV and then we pass certain parameters to some custom methods that we've developed to generate xpath's automatically using the CSV instead of finding those manually as its overhead for us because we already know that all the applications will share similar xpath pattern for all elements.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It completely depends on the application and the type of test you might perform.

Since it is an automated test script, you do not have to really worry about the performance of the script (it might take few more milli seconds to parse, which should be OK).

Maintaining all the elements identification properties & corresponding actions in a CSV file will make the maintenance easier and make the framework application independent which are nice. But maintaining your framework is bit difficult to make it more robust. Both approaches have its own pros and cons.

Refer to below posts [examples are in java - but you will get the idea]:

1. [Keyword driven framework](http://www.testautomationguru.com/keyword-driven-framework-for-localization-testing-using-selenium-webdriver/)
2. [Advanced Page Objects](http://www.testautomationguru.com/arquillian-graphene-page-fragments/)

Update:

If you like both, you can comeup with your implementation to easily integrate these too.

```
@ObjectRepository(src="/login.csv")
public class LoginPage{

    private Map<String, WebElement> elements; 

    public void login(){
        elements.get("username").sendKeys('');
        elements.get("password").sendKeys('');
        elements.get("signin").click();
    }
}
```

Ie, define all the elements in a config file like csv/json etc. Let the page object refer to the class for the page elements. All the methods will be part of the page class.

Comment: I agree with you on this one, what will be your advice if you look at Edit that I have made on this thread? Just to give you an overview we are automating applications built on a cloud base tool so all the applications share the same base structure from HTML standpoint so we decided to define generic xpath patterns in CSV and then using custom methods we pass labels to that csv to generate actual xpath of the element on the fly if we define page objects for every application its an overhead for us as we will have to find those manually instead

Comment: @utkarshs, See, if you are going use this mostly and maintain this in future, let that be in your comfort level. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think, POM is better than CSV approach. In POM, you put elements for a page in a separate class file. So, if any change is to make then it's easier to find where to change/maintain. Moreover, it won't get too messy as CSV file and you don't need to use extra utility function to parse those.

Comment: Actually our use case is bit different then general web application automation, we can never rely on Id's and classes of elements because they change on every refresh so the only option we have is using xpath's now another catch here is if we're navigating to elements using divisions its again loose situation for us because as soon as we move our application to different environment the classes of that element changes as well so we use labels to navigate to elements

Answer (score 2):

There is also a pageobjects gem that provides a set of libraries over and above webdriver/watir, simplifying the code.

Plus, why xpaths? Its one of the last recommended ways to identify an element.

As for the frameork aspect, csv should be more of a maintenance problem than PageObjects. Its the basic difference between text and code. You enforce Object oriented approach on your elements in PageObjects but that is not possible with csv.

In the best case scenario, you have created a column/separate sheets defining which page that element xpath belongs to. That sounds like an overhead. As your application / suite grows there can be thousands of elements. Imagine parsing/ manually updating a csv with that kind of data.

Instead in PageObjects, your elements will be restricted to the Page. Any changes to the app will also specify which elements may get impacted. Now, when define your element as an object in PageObject, rather than css, you also dont need to explicitly create your elements by reading the csv.

Comment: The reason why we go with xpath is our application is dynamic which means on every refresh of the page it changes the id's of each and every element, plus we're doing it on a cloud based technology now if migrate our application from DEV to UAT to PROD then even the classes of divisions changes

Comment: We're actually automating our applications built on a cloud tool so all the applications shares same base structure as far as HTML is concerned so we need not find elements based on pages because there structure will always be same be it be any application on the environment and that's the reason to accelerate our script development we have defined xpath patterns in csv and then generating the actual xpath of element on the fly by passing some parameters to custom methods using those CSV files